Why are parabolic actions `bad'?
I am a newbie in GGT, and it's my second question here.
I was reading "A survey on classifying hyperbolic actions of groups" by S.H Balasubramanya and I came to the following statement in the introduction.
"These actions (parabolic actions), however, retain almost no information about the algebraic structure of the group..."
I want to know what the essential reason for such a problematic behavior of parabolic actions is.
Thank you in advance :)

I think she means that every countable group admits a properly discontinuous parabolic isometric action on a proper geodesic Gromov-hyperbolic space.
